# Windows 7 wakes immediately from sleep - no wake history

Tags: windows-7, sleep, wake-up, powercfg

I have 64-bit Windows 7 Pro installed on a OCZ Vertex 3 SSD. The machine automatically wakes straight up from sleep, whether it happens when after the timeout set in power settings for sleep, or when I manually tell the machine to sleep.

I have tried using the following command to see what device is waking up my computer:

`powercfg /lastwake`

but I always get:

```
Wake History Count - 0
```

I believe it might be related to the SSD, I have tried using the same hardware on a HDD, and have no problems with sleep. I have tried both a Vertex 2 and Vertex 3, and neither would go to sleep, with exactly the same behaviour from powercfg

Answer (score 0):

I am have a totally forgetful moment and will update this when I remember what it's called but SSDs don't have a particular section designated for "going to sleep". This prevents them from using that function. The big reason for this has the do with your RAM I believe and how it plays with the SSD.

Comment: My pc has an SSD and goes to sleep without a problem.

Comment: Which SSD I have an Vertex

Comment: I have an Intel SSD.

Comment: That's most likely why.

Comment: My machine has slept before with the Vertex, when I had Windows 7 installed without any updates, I'm not sure that is the reason why

Comment: Then I do not know.